# polynomial d3-regression loading dataset

Tags: d3.js

I am looking to perform regressions using a package called d3-regression as shown [here](https://observablehq.com/@harrystevens/introducing-d3-regression). There doesn't seem to be a straight forward example of how to create a regression using a set of data.

It looks like you generate the points first and then use a the d3 line functionality to connect them, but I don't see how you enter your data set.

Would anyone be able to provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the source code [here](https://github.com/harrystevens/d3-regression/blob/master/src/polynomial.js) and found that you use it like:

```
 const regression= d3.regressionPoly<DecompressPoint>()
  .x((d: DecompressPoint) => d.extraFloat)
  .y((d: DecompressPoint) => d.criticality)
  .order(3);

const regValues = regression(data);
```